Docker & Redis - dynamically set IP address
I'm running a redis container, which I'm able to connect to fine from my local app using the following url: 'redis://default:redispw@localhost:6379' 
However, this of course will not work when I want to deploy my local app inside of a docker container as well, as I wanted the redis docker container to communicate with my app's container.
Both of these containers are running on the same network, using the following command:
docker run --network bridge  gateway:latest
However, in my code I had to hardcode in the IP of the redis container on that network - something which could of course change if I restart the container.
I am currently using the following url:
'redis://default:redispw@172.17.0.4:6379' 
So my question is, what URL would I connect using so that I don't have to hardcode in a changing IP, or is there a way to set the redis container IP so that it can't change?

Does How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname" answer your question?  So long as both containers are on the same docker run --network (on a docker network created network) then you can use the docker run --name of the container as a host name; you never need to look up the IP address.

Have you tried replacing localhost with host.docker.internal? Depending on your docker deployment (version, os, etc.), that may be just the ticket. Another "trick" is to try 172.17.0.1.
For more on both see these other SO posts:
From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?
What is the Linux equivalent of "host.docker.internal"?
